# How can I connect a knockout observable with jquery barrating plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/

I am using the jquery bar-rating plugin with a knockout viewModel.
Right now, all ratings have to be manually selected, 
but I want to make the variable (let's say rating) into observable
and make the bar change when I type something like

```
viewModel.rating(2);
```

In this case, only two bars will be selected.

Is there an idea how to do  this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make a custom binding to initialize the element and update its value when the observable changes. You can try using something like the following, but I haven't tested it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.barrating = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      $(element).barrating();
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
      var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      $(element).barrating('set', value);
  }
}
```

...

```
<select data-bind="barrating: myRatingObservable">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new to the knockout stuffs. Could you please explain that the 'bindingHandlers' does?

Comment: @user7677413 ko.bindinghandlers is about custom bindings, here more information:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html  Welcome to Knockout. :-)